# Determine why docker image fails to run in swarm mode but works via compose with the same yml file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, docker-swarm-mode

I have the following `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  gateway:
    image: rmilejcz/kalos-gateway:latest
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
    ports:
      - '443:443'
    networks:
      - rpcnet
  rpc:
    image: rmilejcz/kalos-rpc:latest
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
    ports:
      - '8418:8418'
    networks:
      - rpcnet
  proxy:
    image: rmilejcz/grpcwebproxy:latest
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    networks:
      - rpcnet
networks:
  rpcnet:
```

It is essentially an `rpc` server with two separate reverse proxies, `gateway` translates normal HTTP requests and forwards them to `rpc` and `proxy` translates gRPC-web requests and forwards them to `rpc`.

When I run this via `docker-compose up` it works as expected and this is easily confirmed by running:

```
curl localhost:443/v1/lookup/vendor
```

However when I try to run this in a swarm:

```
docker swarm init
docker deploy --compose-file docker-compose.yml test
# OR
docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-compose.yml test
```

The previously working `curl` example returns:

> all SubConns are in TransientFailure, latest connection error: connection error: desc = \"transport: Error while dialing dial tcp: lookup rpc on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host\"

meaning that the `rpc` service is not available. Not sure where `127.0.0.11:53` comes from, I'm guessing `127.0.0.11` is what `rpc` resolves to but I'm not sure what `:53` is derived from.

`docker service ls test_rpc` shows `REPLICAS` at `0/1`. I'm almost certain that for whatever reason, the `rpc` service fails to bind to `rpc:8418` because if I change that to `localhost:8418` and run `docker service ls test_rpc` I can see that `REPLICAS` is at `1/1`, however I am still unable to communicate with that service via either proxy due to the same error above (all subconns in transient failure)

Am I making a bad assumption about container communication within a docker swarm? Is there any way for me to get detailed error information from the `rpc` service to determine exactly why it is failing? If I run `docker-compose up` I can see the services stdout in my terminal, is there some similar capability for docker swarm?

Comment: I don't know anything about Docker Swarm, but port 53 is used for DNS lookups. It seems that one of your containers is trying to look up the host name `rpc` on the server 127.0.0.11, and this lookup fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `docker service ls test_rpc` shows `REPLICAS` at `0/1`. I'm almost certain that for whatever reason, the rpc service fails to bind to `rpc:8418` because if I change that to `localhost:8418` and run `docker service ls test_rpc` I can see that `REPLICAS` is at `1/1`

This sounds like you are talking about the application binding to the port. It should not be binding to `rcp:8418` because, by default in Swarm mode, that will resolve to a VIP that gets routed to each healthy container. Instead, configure your application to bind to `0.0.0.0:8418`. That indicates it should listen locally on all interfaces attached to the container for incoming requests.

Answer (score 1):

`127.0.0.11:53` is the address of DNS server. The `rpc` service is somehow crashing/ not starting, due to which 'gateway' service is unable to forward requests to host `rpc` as there is no such service running on the network and the DNS lookup by `gateway` for `rpc` is returning "no such host".